# Product of sequences proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> $(s_n)$ is a sequence with $\lim s_n = \infty$, and $(t_n)$ is a sequence with $\lim \sup t_n = t < 0$. Prove that 
>   $$\lim s_nt_n = -\infty$$

Proof (can someone please verify it?):

Pick $\epsilon > 0$ such that $t + \epsilon < 0$. Then, $\exists N_1$ such that $\forall n > N_1$, $t_n < t + \epsilon$.

Then, since $(s_n)$ diverges to $\infty$, $\exists N_2$ such that $\forall n > N_2$, $s_n > \displaystyle{\frac{M}{t+\epsilon}}$. Then, $t_ns_n < \displaystyle{\frac{t_nM}{t+\epsilon}} < M$.

Therefore, $s_nt_n$ diverges to $-\infty$.

Comment: At the beginning, you should let $M > 0$. Then technicality in the middle.  Choose $N = \mbox{max}(N_1,N_2)$. If $n > N$ then... Finally at the end you need $s_nt_n < -M$

Comment: Yes your proof is correct. Perhaps you could be a bit more explicit like e.g. fixing $M > 0$ where you pick $\epsilon$. Otherwise good work!